# How to use view model in MVVM?

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, mvvm, request, viewmodel

I'm developing Windows Phone 7 application, and heard that MVVM pattern is useful. I read many articles and questions on this site, but all I get is the explanation of the view model as a bridge between view and model. If model is a Customer class, then the view model is thought to be a collection of customers, used for data binding. This is a very simple usage!

If I want to load customers from network, show it on the view, then store it to local database, should I place all that logic code in the view model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you should not, read about [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). You want only one reason for each of your classes to change, the view-model should only be responsible for translating model information to be presented on the view.

A separate service implementation should be responsible for obtaining the model instances from your data store.

For example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private readonly ICustomerRetrieval _retrievalService;

    public MyViewModel(ICustomerRetrieval retrievalService)
    {
        _retrievalService = retrievalService;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> Customers
    {
        get { return _retrievalService.GetAllCustomers().Select(AsViewModel);
    }

    private CustomerViewModel AsViewModel(CustomerModel cust)
    {
        return new CustomerViewModel(cust);
    }
}
```

You can see the service is responsible for locating the customer models, while the view-model is merely responsible for translating these into something usable from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to load customers from network, show it on the view, then
>   store it to local database, should I place all that logic code in the
>   view model ?

If the logic to "load customers from network" is specific that the view and only that view, then it makes sense to place it into that ViewModel.

If the loading of customers needs to be shared with other Views, then perhaps you should place it in a Data Layer which is loaded at start up or in the background.

The ViewModel should contain code specific to that View only. It shouldn't contain any "core" functionality like loading of data if that data is needed elsewhere by the application.